# Why can't compiler convert callback?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

**SAMPLE CODE**

Using callback works as expected:

```
public void DoWork(object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine(state.ToString());
}

WaitCallback waitCallback = new WaitCallback(this.DoWork);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
   waitCallback, 
   "Via: WaitCallback");
```

Using anonymous method also works:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
   (object stateInfo) => { DoWork(stateInfo); },
   "via: anonymous method");
```

Using delegate with similar signature...

```
AlternateWaitCallback alternateCallback = new AlternateWaitCallback(this.DoWork);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
   alternateWaitCallback, 
   "Via: alternate WaitCallback");
```

...generates a compiler error: *"cannot convert from AlternateWaitCallback to WaitCallback'*

**QUESTION**

I understand that the `delegate` keyword is being used to define two new types that will act as callbacks.  What I don't understand is: why can the compiler match the method signature of the *anonymous method* against `WaitCallback`... but it can't do the same for `AlternateWaitCallback`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why can the compiler match the method signature of the anonymous method against `WaitCallback`... but it can't do the same for `AlternateWaitCallback`?

An anonymous method has no intrinsic type (in other words, it's not definitely typed); it's just convertible to any delegate type with a compatible signature (`WaitCallback` in this case). `AlternateWaitCallback`, on the other hand, is its own type; you can't convert a type to another unless they have an inheritance relation or there is a conversion defined between them.